# How to create a vertical dotted line between icons (with example image)

Tags: html, css

After trying numerous things and searching the web I still can't find out how to create a similar vertical dotted line between the icons as shown in the image. Someone an idea on how to achieve this? Any help will be much appreciated!!
[image]

**Note**: It's not a screenshot from a website
so I wasn't able to look at the source code :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using `border-left`.

Check this fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NBMRp/607/)

```css
.icon {
    text-align: center;
    width: 50px;
    background: lightgray;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid grey;
}

.icon > i {
  margin: 33% auto;
}

.dotted:after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    height: inherit;
    border-left: 2px dotted lightgrey;
}

.dotted {
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="dotted">
  <div class="icon">
    <i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="icon">
    <i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old request, but I've been working for a while on an entirely css solution for "icon to icon connected by a dotted line".  I was able to achieve by setting up two icons within a container div, then connecting with a dotted line using a :before pseudo element on the container div where content is a long series of periods (ie. content: "........").  I then used writing-mode and text-orientation CSS, and some flexbox to line things up. This approach is the most versatile solution. It allowed me to use different weight fonts and letter spacing to fully adjust the dots to my liking.

```css
.container:before {
    content: ".............................................................................................................................";
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden; /* hide overflow on wrappers accordingly */
    font-weight: 800; /* using periods allows for customization of weight */
    letter-spacing: -8px; /* allows you to adjust dot spacing */
    writing-mode: vertical-rl; /* use for vertical orientation */
    text-orientation: upright; /* use for vertical orientation */
    z-index: -1; /* was needed to get my dots below my icons */
}
```

```
<div class="container">
    <i class="icon"></i>
    <i class="icon"></i>
</div>
```